# addEventListener and gotoAndStop for a menu in a game gives error

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, menu, addeventlistener, submenu

I'm new at flash as3. Today, I am trying to code a menu in a game which will refer to a startscreen for a game to show the buttons for the game.

In this startscreen, there is a button to link back to the menu. It doesn't work. I am getting this,

Error:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at SuperSpill_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()
```

Comment: Can you post the code that contains the line above, plus the body of the musSpill function?

Comment: all the code is above

Comment: Since you have more frames, it needs to see the Fla file itself. May be on one of your frame, that target object is not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like to me the only possible thing that could have happened is that mus doesn't exist anymore. This suggests that the code is running in a frame where mus is no longer on stage.

I would expect that in most versions of the Flash Player that the frame wouldn't fully render between goToAndStop and the next line, but my suggestion would be to either swap the order of those lines or change it to

```
event.currentTarget.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, musSpill)
```

Comment: anything I do, I always get this message: TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at SuperSpill_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()

Comment: The event listener can't trigger unless mus is on screen, so I would assume that you are still on that frame when the listener first fires. But when you goToAndStop(), there is no guarantee that it is still there. Given the error, I think it must not be.

Comment: You may be getting null pointer exceptions out of some of your other event listeners now, if you followed my suggestion only on one of them.